# jQuery DataTables serverside refresh issue when less rows are received on refresh compared to initial load

Tags: datatables

I am using bStateSave with bServerside on DataTables 1.9.4. I initially load the table which has 1000 rows and I navigate to the last page which has row numbers 951 to 1000. Then on reloading the page with a different query which has only 500 rows, due to bStatesave, the iDisplayStart value remains 950 and thus no data is displayed in the table and the info section of datatable says - "Showing 950 to 500 of 500 entries"

This is my initialization code.

```
var oTable = $('#sampleTable').dataTable({
"sScrollY":"500px",
"bProcessing":true,
"bServerSide":true,
"bStateSave":true,
"sDom":'Crtipl',
"sAjaxSource":"../test.htmlx",
"iDisplayLength":50,
"bPaginate":true,
"sPaginationType":"bootstrap",
"aoColumns": [
        {"mDataProp": "id"},
        {"mDataProp": function(source){
           return "<pre>"+source.description+"</pre>" 
        }},
        {"mDataProp": createdBy"} 
        ],
"fnRowCallback":function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex){
        $(nRow).on('click',$(nRow),function(){
        document.location.href="edit.htmlx"
        });
        }
 });
```

Ideally either the table should be at the last page showing 451 to 500 entries or start from 1st page showing 1 to 50 entries.
bStateSave has to be true to save the column sorting information on reload.
How to solve this problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are API function in DataTables and of these, **fnDisplayStart()** (http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnDisplayStart) will solve this problem.
After the initialization, I just have to make a call to
oTable.fnDisplayStart(0)  and the table will point to 1st page.